# How to find signed assembly pfx password from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, passwords, visual-studio-2019, dynamics-crm-2011, pfx

I signed an assembly on Visual Studio and created a key `pfx` file.

Everything works fine on my computer across different versions of Visual Studio.

However, a work colleague is unable to build the solution as they require the password (which I have since forgotten).

Is it possible to recover this password from my computer?

How does my Visual Studio environment remember the pfx password?